# Function in web app slower than standard function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Are functions [created as a web app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/) slower on first load than a regular function?

I have a HttpTrigger as a normal function (in a .csx), and one in a web app. And it feels like the first response is slow on the web app one. Subsequent calls are fine. Feels like the first one just woke it up.

In a normal function I haven't really experienced that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by function in a web app, you're referring to the pre-compiled model using a web app project, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Cold start performance will be **better** when using the pre-compiled model (as there is no need for a compilation step). What you may be observing as a comparison between cold start (for the web app based version) and a warm host (for the CSX), as changes to your CSX will not trigger a host reload, just a recompilation of your function, where redeploying a pre-compiled function does.

If you restart both sites and compare first request performance, you should see a better results with the pre-compiled version (those may be variable and will be more noticeable if you have a larger number of functions)

Comment: yes, I was expecting it to be better, but it definitely feels noticeably worse the first time it's called (after a long period), then subsequent calls are fine. Think I'll set up a timer trigger to ping it regularly and see if  i notice the slowness...

Comment: Again, this experience may vary based on other factors like worker allocation, remote file IO latency, etc.. But if you do observe increased latency, please open an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) and we'll investigate.